# Some type of Mixed Integer Nonlinear Programming Problem

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, nonlinear-optimization

This is a minimisation problem, to minimise the integral over possible $0\leq t \leq T$, $T$ is free,

$$J = \text{min} \int_0^T (\alpha + \beta_1\cdot v \cdot R_T \cdot q+ \beta_2 \cdot \frac{M}{1000} \cdot v \cdot a^2 \cdot p \cdot q)\,dt$$

where,

$$R_T = b_1 + b_2 \cdot v^2 + \frac{M}{1000}\cdot a$$

$$ p = \text{sgn}(a) =
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{if $a > 0$}  \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

$$ q = \text{sgn}(R_T) =
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{if $R_T > 0$}  \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

$s$ is travel distance, $v$ is velocity, $a$ is acceleration and subject to dynamics,
$$
\begin{cases}
\dot s(t)= v(t)\text{;}\ v(0) = 0\text{,}\ s(T) = D \\
\dot v(t)= a(t)\text{;}\ a(0) = 0
\end{cases}
$$

In the above expressions, $\alpha$, $\beta_1$, $\beta_2$, $b_1$, $b_2$, $M$, $D$ are constants.

Any suggestions about computing the minimum $J$ are greatly appreciated. (Is there any routine in matlab that solves this problem?)

Answer (score 1):

One option is [APM MATLAB](http://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/MATLAB) that allows differential and algebraic equations with either continuous or mixed integer variables. You'll need to define the differential of the objective function and include it as a constraint. You can then include the integral of that variable in the objective function declaration.